# Documentation of Helidon MP configuration options

Tags: java, configuration, microprofile, helidon

Is there a documentation that lists all configuration options of Helidon MP, what they control, their default and allowed values?

The official [Configuring the Server](https://helidon.io/docs/v2/#/mp/jaxrs/02_server-configuration) guide focuses for on in what way the configuration can come from, but not much on what can be configured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configuration reference for all configurable objects of Helidon (both SE and MP):
https://helidon.io/docs/v3/#/config/config_reference

Answer (score 0):

We currently don't have a single documentation which list all possible config option for Helidon MP and are working on providing that as part of https://github.com/oracle/helidon/issues/3463

The doc you linked is giving example of how to configure as well as what to configure e.g. properties needed for TLS etc. If you can specify, what you want to configure on MP server or other component, we should be able to provide reference for the same.